# Syntax error: expecting identifier before this. expecting colon before leftparen. expecting identifier before rightbrace

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, syntax-error

```
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 9    1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 9    1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 10   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 16   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 16   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 17   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 23   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 23   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 24   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 30   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 30   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 31   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 37   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 37   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 38   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 44   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 44   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 45   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 51   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 51   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 52   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 58   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 58   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 59   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 65   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 65   1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
Scene 1, Layer 'script', Frame 1, Line 66   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
```

these errors (27 of them) show up and my stop command wont work, whats wrong with my code?? i'm new to flash action script, and i used a youtube tutorial to create the buttons (knapp) i refere to.

here's my code

```
stop();

//knappane til dei forskjellige planetane

//solen
solenKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToSolen);

function goToSolen(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("solen")
}

//merkur
merkurKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToMerkur);

function goToMerkur(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("merkur")
}

//venus
venusKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToVenus);

function goToVenus(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("venus")
}

//jorden
jordenKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToJorden);

function goToJorden(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("jorden")
}

//mars
marsKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToMars);

function goToMars(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("mars")
}

//jupiter
jupiterKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToJupiter);

function goToJupiter(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("jupiter")
}

//saturn
saturnKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToSaturn);

function goToSaturn(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("saturn")
}

//uranus
uranusKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToUranus);

function goToUranus(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("uranus")
}

//neptun
neptunKnappen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToNeptun);

function goToNeptun(event: MouseEvent);void {
this.gotoAndStop("neptun")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code's error is when using a **semicolon** ( `;` ) to indicate the types of your functions instead of using a **colon** ( `:` ), so the code for your `goToSolen()` function, for example, should be like this :

```
function goToSolen(event: MouseEvent): void 
{
    this.gotoAndStop("solen");
}
```

And of course you should do that with all your functions.

For more about functions in ActionScript 3, take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html).

Hope that can help.